# If $\frac{a}{k} - \frac{a(c-1)}{kb} > 1$, is $\frac{a}{k+1} - \frac{a(c-1)}{(k+1)b} > 1$?

Tags: inequality, induction, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying an induction method, but not sure if I'm able to prove it or find a counterexample.

Suppose $3 \leq a < b$ and $1 \leq c \leq b$, and $k \geq 1$, where $a, b, c, k$ are integers.

Suppose $n = 1$ is proven. Then inductive hypothesis is
$$\frac{a}{k} - \frac{a(c-1)}{kb} > 1$$
Is the following true? $$\frac{a}{k+1} - \frac{a(c-1)}{(k+1)b} > 1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Take $a-\frac{a(c-1)}{b}=k+\frac{1}{4}.$

We have $$\frac{a}{k}-\frac{a(c-1)}{kb}=1+\frac{1}{4k}>1,$$ but
$$\frac{a}{k+1}-\frac{a(c-1)}{(k+1)b}=\frac{k+\frac{1}{4}}{k+1}<1.$$

Comment: Thanks! Would it still hold if $a, b, c, k$ are integers?

Comment: @Nicholas Take $a=3$, $b=4,$ $c=2$ and $k=2$.

Comment: Oh but we have the condition $b > a$

Comment: @Nicholas I fixed my previous comment.

Comment: I see, thanks for the example!